# Delete a sub-array by a specific duplicate field value

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have:

```
multy_array = [
  [Jack, Fred, Jane],
  [Paul, Mattew, Gina],
  [Jack, Bart, Hector],
  [Jhon, Veronica, Nicole],
  [Marcella, Vianka, Richard]
]
```

I want to keep only one sub-array that presents the unique element in index `[0][0]` of the array, i.e., `Jack`. So I should keep only the first sub-array with `Jack`, and drop the other entire sub-array at index `[2]`. I want:

```
[
  [Jack, Fred, Jane],
  [Paul, Mattew, Gina],
  [Jhon, Veronica, Nicole],
  [Marcella, Vianka, Richard]
]
```

Comment: It would help us if that was valid Ruby syntax, as in either that's an array of strings (`%w[ Jack Fred Jane ]`) or an array of Symbols (`[:Jack, :Fred, :Jane]`). Right now that code needs a lot of work to become valid for testing purposes.

Comment: Do you want to use [`uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq) with a block to define the "uniqueness constraint"?

Comment: Do you want to remove any subsequent arrays with the *same first element* as the first array? Or do you want to remove any subsequent arrays with *any element* equal to the first element of the first array?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the duplicated field value is on the first array, it could have been on the third or fifth array..my goal is too keep only one array that contains that value(Jack) and entirely remove the other arrays which contains that exact value at index 0.

Comment: Okay - so you want to drop any array that has a value that has already been included in a previous array?

Comment: I have edited/updated my answer to meet your request.

Comment: @tadman it is a valid reference to the `Jack` class :)

Comment: I found the solution to my problem. new_array = multy_array.uniq {|x| x.first}

Answer (score 2):

Other option building a Hash ([`Enumerable#to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h)), where keys are uniques by definition:

```
multy_array.reverse.map { |e| [e.first, e] }.to_h.values
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove arrays that contain the **first** element of the **first** array in **any** position, it would be a simple `Array#reject`, something like this:

`multi_array.reject { |arr| arr != multi_array[0] && arr.include?(multi_array[0][0]) }`

Here, you are creating a new array by rejecting any member of the `multi_array` that is not the first member and also includes that value.

```
irb(main):001:0> multi_array = [%w[Jack Fred Jane], %w[Paul Matthew Gina], %w[Jack Bart Hector], %w[John Veronica Nicole], %w[Marcella Vianka Richard]]

=> [["Jack", "Fred", "Jane"], ["Paul", "Matthew", "Gina"], ["Jack", "Bart", "Hector"], ["John", "Veronica", "Nicole"], ["Marcella", "Vianka", "Richard"]]

irb(main):016:0> multi_array.reject { |arr| arr != multi_array[0] && arr.include?(multi_array[0][0]) }

=> [["Jack", "Fred", "Jane"], ["Paul", "Matthew", "Gina"], ["John", "Veronica", "Nicole"], ["Marcella", "Vianka", "Richard"]]
```

EDIT:

This is my first answer that assumed you wanted to remove a sub-array if it had a duplicate of any value from any previous sub-array.

You can use `#each_with_object` to build a result of only those arrays that do not have any duplicated values from the previous arrays like this:

`multi_array.each_with_object([]) { |a, result| result << a unless a.any? { |b| result.flatten.include?(b) } }`

You are stepping through the arrays and adding each to the result, as long as none of its values are already in the flattened result.

```
irb(main):004:0> multi_array.each_with_object([]) { |a, result| result << a unless a.any? { |b| result.flatten.include?(b) } }

=> [["Jack", "Fred", "Jane"], ["Paul", "Matthew", "Gina"], ["John", "Veronica", "Nicole"], ["Marcella", "Vianka", "Richard"]]
```

Here, I add "Richard" to the second array and you can see that both the second "Jack" and the second "Richard" arrays are removed.

```
irb(main):009:0> multi_array = [%w[Jack Fred Jane], %w[Paul Matthew Richard], %w[Jack Bart Hector], %w[John Veronica Nic ole], %w[Marcella Vianka Richard]]

=> [["Jack", "Fred", "Jane"], ["Paul", "Matthew", "Richard"], ["Jack", "Bart", "Hector"], ["John", "Veronica", "Nicole"], ["Marcella", "Vianka", "Richard"]]

irb(main):010:0> multi_array.each_with_object([]) { |a, result| result << a unless a.any? { |b| result.flatten.include?(b) } }

=> [["Jack", "Fred", "Jane"], ["Paul", "Matthew", "Richard"], ["John", "Veronica", "Nicole"]]
```

Comment: Interesting to note here, that if you add Richard to the *third* array instead of the second, then the second "Richard" array will be included in the result, not the first. This is because the first "Richard" was also the second "Jack" array, and was thus discarded.

Comment: Actually the first solution code was working perfectly, i only need to eliminate the duplicate on the index[0] on the other index is fine if there is duplicate..can you edit it back? ^^

Comment: But this one is so much more interesting. :) Done. Happy hacking!